# How do you dynamically adjust the recursion depth for eager loading in the SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, adjacency-list, recursive-query

I have a two-table hierarchical setup where table A references table B, which then references back to a different record in table A, and so on... but only up to a given recursion depth.

I have this working well using SQLAlchemy and declarative.  I'm also successfully using eager loading with the `lazy` and `join_depth` properties on the table relations.  This is as per the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/07/orm/relationships.html?highlight=adjacency%20list#configuring-eager-loading).

However, this arrangement fixes the recursion depth at '`join_depth`' once at program load time...  but with the data I am using I know the recursion depth I should be using each time.  **How can I change the recursion depth used on a per-query basis?**

I've considered fiddling with the master `join_depth` property on the base ORM object, but this won't work since I've got a multi-threaded scoped_session application where that would be dangerous (not to mention the fact that the parameter is pretty hard to locate within SQLAlchemy at runtime!).

I've also looked at using `joinedload` with the query but don't see how to vary the depth with that.

I'm also aware of the '`WITH RECURSIVE`' SQL syntax available in some databases via [CTEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions), but as great as it is, I want to avoid that for the moment since some DBs still don't support it (and neither does SQLAlchemy - at least not at the moment and not without a lot of dialect customization).

Answer (score 7):

There's no official way to do this, but following the code produced the following solution for me.  I'm using the Node example from the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html?highlight=adjacency%2520list#configuring-self-referential-eager-loading) you linked.

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Node",
                    lazy="joined",
                    join_depth=2)
```

At creation time, the `children` property is given a `join_depth` of 2.  This initial value is recorded in `Node.children.property.join_depth`.  However, changing this value will not do anything.  At init, the relationship creates a "strategy" for joining, and this copies the `join_depth` value.  **To change the join depth of the strategy for the relationship, you set `Node.children.property.strategy.join_depth`.**

```
>>> engine.echo = True  # print generated queries
>>> session.query(Node).all()  # with default join_depth
SELECT node.id AS node_id, node.parent_id AS node_parent_id, node.data AS node_data, node_1.id AS node_1_id, node_1.parent_id AS node_1_parent_id, node_1.data AS node_1_data, node_2.id AS node_2_id, node_2.parent_id AS node_2_parent_id, node_2.data AS node_2_data FROM node LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS node_2 ON node.id = node_2.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS node_1 ON node_2.id = node_1.parent_id
>>> Node.children.property.strategy.join_depth = 4  # new join depth
>>> session.query(Node).all()  # with new join depth
SELECT node.id AS node_id, node.parent_id AS node_parent_id, node.data AS node_data, node_1.id AS node_1_id, node_1.parent_id AS node_1_parent_id, node_1.data AS node_1_data, node_2.id AS node_2_id, node_2.parent_id AS node_2_parent_id, node_2.data AS node_2_data, node_3.id AS node_3_id, node_3.parent_id AS node_3_parent_id, node_3.data AS node_3_data, node_4.id AS node_4_id, node_4.parent_id AS node_4_parent_id, node_4.data AS node_4_data FROM node LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS node_4 ON node.id = node_4.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS node_3 ON node_4.id = node_3.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS node_2 ON node_3.id = node_2.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS node_1 ON node_2.id = node_1.parent_id
```

After setting `Node.children.property.strategy.join_depth`, the number of joins in the generated query changes as well.